# iOS Auto-Layout: How should I calculate cell height correctly in this scenario?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As you can see in this picture
[image]

, the `imageView`'s size is fixed and I want to have the cell's subviews "exert pressure" and make the content view expand to fit them. Let the intrinsic content size of these subviews drive the height of the table view cell's content view. It's obvious that the cell height depends on the maximum height of `messageButton` and `imageView`:

How should I add those constraints?

Comment: https://mkswap.net/m/ios/2015/07/08/uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-height.html

Comment: @Sachin Vas thanks man it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

but before that, you should use Auto-layout to add constraints correctly, you don't need think about the imageView and the button height, just add the constraints of distance to the bottom and top. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```